# Limit the number of items in if statement, after a while loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom-made calendar lister in wordpress, which gets the custom-post type Events, which have an ACF field with the Events' date and compares it with today's date to list it. I want to limit the number of the posts to 5, but with the logic that filters out 5 events in the while loop the older events also get in the filter and count in the 5, so in the end with the comparison they are also counted in, and for eg. if I have 2 older events only 3 are show in the if statement. 
Here is the code:

```
    $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'events', 'meta_key'=>'date', 'orderby'=>'meta_value', 'order'=>'ASC', 'posts_per_page'=>5 );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

    $title = get_the_title();

    $maindate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('date'));
    $today = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', date('Ymd'));

if ( $maindate >= $today ) :
```

... + then the html code with the elements

Any idea how can I restructure it?

Comment: So you want to leave the loop after it has gone over five posts, no matter whether it has actually output them or not? Well then increase a counter _outside_ of the if that performs that date check. If you want it the other way around, do it inside of it.  Then either check your counter value at the end and break out of the loop, or make that check part of the loop condition to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to list the 5 upcoming events, and leave out the old ones. You now filter them in your while loop, but you can better filter them in your query.

ACF uses Wordpress meta fields (see [this link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/)), so you can query on those as well. This would come down to something like this:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'events', 
    'meta_key'=>'date', 
    'meta_query' => [
        ['key' => 'date', 
         'value' => date('Y-m-d'), 
         'compare' => '>=']
     ],  
     'orderby'=>'meta_value', 
     'order'=>'ASC', 
     'posts_per_page'=>5 );
```

Comment: Thank you Frank! I managed it to get it work, but I had to change the comparison value to be compatible with the ACF date format, so it is the simple php "date('Ymd')" and not "DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', date('Ymd'))"

Comment: Good to hear you managed to get it to work! I have updated my answer for others to find the right answer ;-).